# Android: Problem with fireStore to convert an array of mappable to Objects

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I can't resolve my problem.

I have an array of mappable in my Firestore database as you can see on the screen

[image]

Then I would like to load this list and convert all of the items in an object like this one

[image]

And my code to convert my list of mappable to objects is here

[image]

I got an error telling

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to
> com.example.gestionnairedechantiers.firebase.ItemWithQuantity

The first log returns

[image]

I don't understand why could you help me, please? I don't find a way to convert an array of mappable to a list of objects.

Thank you very much

EDIT: A solution, maybe the best one ?

[image]

I convert my items from the list to HashMap, an then I convert to my Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see in your screenshot, the "listePersonnel" is a property of type array that contains "ItemWithQuantity" objects. When you are calling DocumentSnapshot's [get(String field) method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#get(java.lang.String)), the object that is returned is actually a HashMap and **not** a List, as you probably expected.

To map that array into a List, please check the following article:

- [How to map an array of objects from Cloud Firestore to a List of objects?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10)

Basically, you should create a new class that will hold a property called "listePersonnel" of type List and map each document into an object of that type:

```
val listePersonnel: List<ItemWithQuantity> = document.toObject(NewClass.class).listePersonnel
```

**Edit:**

> I don't know if I can retrieve my field listePersonnel from my document as a DocumentSnapshot.

There is no way you can retrieve the "listePersonnel" and convert it to a DocumentSnapshot object. What you should do is convert the entire document into an object of the "NewClass", and then get the list, like any other property of the class.

> In the article, the author uses .toObject() to convert its list to an object and you can only use it with a DocumentSnapshot.

The author (me), I'm using ".toObject()" to convert that entire document into an object that contains the desired list.

> I get my document with different fields, and I want to convert a field which is a list of mappables to a list of objects.

In your database, that field is an array of objects. So you need to convert that array into a list of custom objects (as explained in this answer and that article).

> I use document.get("list"), I get a Any/HashMap.

That's what we are talking about, not to use get("list") as it returns a Map, that should be iterated, as you already did, but to get that fields directly to a list of "NewClass" objects.

Comment: Hello Alex, thank you for the answer ! I've seen this article but in my case I didn't achieve to use it because I don't know if I can retrieve my field listePersonnel from my document as a DocumentSnapshot. In the article, the autor uses .toObject() to convert its list to an object and you can only use it with a DocumentSnapshot. In my case, I get my document with differents fields, and I want to convert a filed which is a list of mappables to a list of objects.  So when I use document.get("list"), I get a Any/HashMap.

Comment: I've added a solution I found, I don't know if it's the best one

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I hope it's more clear now.